# Audio book for the Malazan Book of the Fallen?

Tags: malazan

I am trying to find the audio book version of the Steve Erikson series. Were these audio books ever created? If they exist, where can I find them?I can't find them at any major online audio book store.

Comment: Uhhhh....you could just torrent them. The audio books for ALL 10 books, as far as I know, have been released.

Answer (score 3):

The [isfdb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?20728) page seems to suggest no. I think that's conclusive, but it could be incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

The Gardens of the Moon audiobook was recently released (9/2012). It's available from Amazon and Audible.com (owned by Amazon), though it's not available in all countries (e.g. Australia).

Answer (score 2):

first 3 books in the malazan book of the fallen series were released consecutively each month right after the release of Forge of Darkness: Kharkanas Trilogy, Book 1. I assume the next 3 would be released when book 2 of the kharkanas trilogy(working title Fall of Light ) is released.

Answer (score 2):

There is an audio book for [Gardens of the Moon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009L65JEG).

And here is one for [The Deadhouse Gates](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BJOGMY4).

And here is one for the [Crippled God](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011AZMLF0).

All the books in between also have audiobooks.

There are even audiobooks for related novels, such as [Night of Knives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01E4G7GYS).

It appears that they are all free with an Audible trial, so that might be the best way to listen to them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say they're too long to justify the production costs...900-1100 pages per book? A dozen or so books? You'd have to reach full-on mega bestseller status for that to happen.